# MailboxProcessor and exceptions

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

I wonder, why `MailboxProcessor`'s default strategy of handling exceptions is just *silently ignore* them. For example:

```
let counter =
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop() =
            async { printfn "waiting for data..."
                    let! data = inbox.Receive()
                    failwith "fail" // simulate throwing of an exception
                    printfn "Got: %d" data
                    return! loop()
            }
        loop ())
()
counter.Post(42)
counter.Post(43)
counter.Post(44)
Async.Sleep 1000 |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

and nothing happens. There is no fatal stop of the program execution, or message box with "An unhandled exception" arises. Nothing.

This situation becomes worse if someone uses `PostAndReply` method: a guaranteed deadlock as the result.

Any reasons for such behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason why the `MailboxProcessor` in F# does not contain any mechanism for handling exceptions is that it is not clear what is the best way for doing that. For example, you may want to have a global event that is triggered when an unhandled exception happens, but you may want to rethrow the exception on the next call to `Post` or `PostAndReply`.

Both of the options can be implemented based on the standard `MailboxProcessor`, so it is possible to add the behaviour you want. For example, the following snippet shows `HandlingMailbox` that adds a global exception handler. It has the same interface as normal `MailboxProcessor` (I omitted some methods), but it adds `OnError` event that is triggered when an exception happens:

```
type HandlingMailbox<'T> private(f:HandlingMailbox<'T> -> Async<unit>) as self =
  let event = Event<_>()
  let inbox = new MailboxProcessor<_>(fun inbox -> async {
    try 
      return! f self
    with e ->
      event.Trigger(e) })
  member x.OnError = event.Publish
  member x.Start() = inbox.Start()
  member x.Receive() = inbox.Receive()
  member x.Post(v:'T) = inbox.Post(v)
  static member Start(f) =
    let mbox = new HandlingMailbox<_>(f)
    mbox.Start()
    mbox
```

To use it, you would write the same code as what you wrote before, but you can now handle exceptions asynchronously:

```
let counter = HandlingMailbox<_>.Start(fun inbox -> async {
  while true do 
    printfn "waiting for data..." 
    let! data = inbox.Receive() 
    failwith "fail" })

counter.OnError.Add(printfn "Exception: %A")
counter.Post(42)
```

Comment: Yes, it can be implemented, of course. I don't understand, why *default* behavior is so speechless. It can re-throw exception in case of there is no handlers in `MailboxProcessor.add_Error`, for example.
It's difficult to debug Async/multithreaded code. Why should we make this task even harder?

Comment: You can argue that it would be better to take down the process (unhandled exception) if no handlers have been attached.  I don't recall the rationale.

Comment: One problem with rethrowing exceptions is that you lose the stack trace - for example `async{failwith "bad"}` gives a stack trace pointing deep in the F# libs, which can be annoying debugging - apparently this is a .NET limitation on rethrowing exceptions on a different thread

Answer (score 17):

There is an `Error` event on the MailboxProcessor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340481

```
counter.Error.Add(fun e -> printfn "%A" e)
```

Of course, you can do something like Tomas' solution if you want to exert fine control yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know about this member `Error`. I wonder why default on Error handler does not do anything. It can re-throw, or write to stderr, or halt application -- anything is better than just silently ignore exceptions.

Comment: Doh! I was looking for an existing event on standard `MailboxProcessor`, but somehow I completely missed the `Error` event...

Comment: Note that you can also `raise` the exception instead of printing it, if you want your program to crash when a `MailboxProcessor` fails instead of continuing to run in a potentially-broken state.