# Unifying Task<T> and F# MailboxProcessor exception handling

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

When using Task<T>, an exception during the execution of the task is thrown during Task.Wait(); when using F#'s MailBoxProcessor, the exception gets swallowed and needs to be explicitly dealt with as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805035/mailboxprocessor-and-exceptions).

This difference makes it difficult to expose F# agents to C# code via a Task. For example, this agent:

```
type internal IncrementMessage = 
    Increment of int * AsyncReplyChannel<int>

type IncrementAgent() =
    let counter = Agent.Start(fun agent -> 
        let rec loop() = async { let! Increment(msg, replyChannel) = agent.Receive()
                                match msg with 
                                | int.MaxValue -> return! failwith "Boom!"
                                | _ as i -> replyChannel.Reply (i + 1)
                                            return! loop() }

        loop())

    member x.PostAndAsyncReply i =
        Async.StartAsTask (counter.PostAndAsyncReply (fun channel -> Increment(i, channel)))
```

can be called from C#, but the exception is not returned to C#:

```cs
[Test]
public void ExceptionHandling()
{
    //
    // TPL exception behaviour
    //
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => { throw new Exception("Boom!"); });

    try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch(AggregateException e)
    {
        // Exception available here
        Console.WriteLine("Task failed with {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
    }

    //
    // F# MailboxProcessor exception behaviour
    //
    var incAgent = new IncrementAgent();
    task = incAgent.PostAndAsyncReply(int.MaxValue);

    try
    {
        task.Wait(); // deadlock here
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Agent failed with {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Instead of getting the exception, the C# code just hangs at task.Wait(). Is there any way to get the F# agent to behave like a Task? If not, it seems like there is limited use in exposing F# agents to other .NET code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle it is have the agent return a DU with an error case. You could then raise the exception from outside the agent.

```
type internal IncrementResponse =
    | Response of int
    | Error of exn

type internal IncrementMessage = 
    | Increment of int * AsyncReplyChannel<IncrementResponse>

type IncrementAgent() =
    let counter = Agent.Start(fun agent -> 
        let rec loop() = 
          async { 
            let! Increment(msg, replyChannel) = agent.Receive()
            match msg with 
            | int.MaxValue -> replyChannel.Reply (Error (Failure "Boom!"))
            | _ as i -> replyChannel.Reply (Response(i + 1))
            return! loop() 
          }
        loop())

    member x.PostAndAsyncReply i =
        Async.StartAsTask (
          async {
            let! res = counter.PostAndAsyncReply (fun channel -> Increment(i, channel))
            match res with
            | Response i -> return i
            | Error e -> return (raise e)
          }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! I haven't got my head around `return (raise e)` being a legal construct, even though my code used a similar `return! failwith "Boom!"`.

Comment: `raise` is defined as returning `'T`, but of course it never really returns at all. This allows it to be used anywhere, regardless of the enclosing expression's type.

Comment: @Akash: You could also write: `return match res with Response i -> i | Error e -> raise e`.