# Restart MailboxProcessor after failure?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, mailboxprocessor

I'm trying to get started working with agents in F# via the `MailboxProcessor<'Msg>` class, and I quickly realized I had no proper handling for exceptions. In a Haskellian world, there wouldn't be any exceptions, and so the proper way to handle issues would be to simply provide them as a response case; so an agent could reply with something like:

```
type AgentResponse =
    | HandledData of string
    | InvalidData of string
```

One could then call the agent's `.PostAndReply` method and get an `InvalidData` containing a message indicating why the data is invalid. However, this isn't Haskell, and sometimes exceptions happen. So if I do this:

```
let agent =
    new MailboxProcessor<string * AsyncReplyChannel<AgentResponse>>(fun inbox ->
        async {
            while true do
                let! (msg, replyChannel) = inbox.Receive()
                if msg = "die" then failwith "Unknown exception encountered!"
                else replyChannel.Reply(HandledData(msg))
        })

agent.Start()
agent.PostAndReply (fun rc -> "die", rc)
agent.PostAndReply (fun rc -> "Test", rc)
```

The second call to `agent.PostAndReply` blocks indefinitely. When not using `AsyncReplyChannel` and therefore just calling `agent.Post`, the calls don't block, but once the agent encounters an exception, new messages just stay in the queue. Restarting the agent in either case appears impossible, as the `agent.Start` function returns an `InvalidOperationException` when called again, and the natural way to handle this seems to be to create a new agent with a clean state, but then all queued messages are lost.

Beyond just wrapping the entire body of an agent in `try..with`, is there any good way to get an agent to continue running after an exception? Alternatively, has a "standard" way of dealing with this been established that someone can point me to?

Comment: I think the whole idea of a `MailboxProcessor` (agent) is that it dies on failure.  Maybe you could use another agent as a queue, and then use `TryPostAndReply` where the queue agent spins up a new agent when there is an error?  If you're needing high performance, I'm thinking `try...catch` is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @mydogisbox Just catching everything seems like a less-than-optimal idea, but I agree it also seems like the best way to go. The issue I'm looking to avoid is having to keeping two copies of the queued messages; e.g., if I wrote a mailer daemon in F#. The daemon shouldn't "lose" queued emails just because the agent hit a network exception I hadn't thought to catch, so it would need to keep the messages elsewhere as well as in the queue. Feels like it defeats the purpose of the agent having a queue if I need a second copy of everything in said queue.

Comment: I agree.  I wonder how the erlang agent model handles this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You do have exceptions in Haskell : try `Data.List.head []` in ghci....

Unfortunately, lack of dependent types means, in Haskell or in F#, that we can write type correct code which has no computational meaning.

Practically, wrapping the with a `try ... with` block is not a bad idea for dealing with exception. You dont need to wrap the entire body, just the non-pure part of your code though.

Then classically, you yield back a value made with the appropriate constructor.

Comment: "just the non-pure part of your code" in .NET, wouldn't that be all of it? :) Waiting and wishing the pure keyword would happen: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5670335-pure-functions-pure-keyword

Comment: Perhaps, but unenforced pure code at that; at that point, why have languages like Haskell at all? Besides it being rather difficult to determine which objects in the BCL (and third-party libs) are safe to use in a pure manner.

Comment: @nicolas : A rather unfair comparison, since C doesn't have exceptions (ignoring floating-point signals), whereas 90% of BCL methods may throw.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option is a helper type similar to the `HandlingMailbox` defined by Tomas Petricek over at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805035/mailboxprocessor-and-exceptions), which runs the body of the agent repeatedly:

```
type ResilientMailbox<'T> private(f:ResilientMailbox<'T> -> Async<unit>) as self =
    let event = Event<_>()
    let inbox = new MailboxProcessor<_>(fun _inbox ->
        let rec loop() = async {
            try
                return! f self
            with e ->
                event.Trigger(e)
                return! loop()
            }
        loop())
    member __.OnError = event.Publish
    member __.Start() = inbox.Start()
    member __.Receive() = inbox.Receive()
    member __.Post(v:'T) = inbox.Post(v)
    static member Start(f) =
        let mbox = new ResilientMailbox<_>(f)
        mbox.Start()
        mbox
```

This can be started and run like a normal `MailboxProcessor`, but will re-run itself if the provided agent body throws an exception.

Edit: Change the inner `MailboxProcessor` to use a recursive function versus a `while true do..` block; the previous code would not stop running when the target function returned normally.