# mailboxprocessor does not terminate

Tags: f#, timeout, mailboxprocessor

I have a timeout exception (and I really intend to set a timeout) inside a message loop and I have tried to catch it as follows

```
let printerAgent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox-> 
    // the message processing function
    let rec messageLoop() = async{
        try
            // read a message
            let! msg = inbox.Receive 30000
            // process a message
            match msg with
            | Message text ->
                sw.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortTimeString(), text)
                printfn "%s" text
                // loop to top
                return! messageLoop()  
            | Shutdown replyChannel ->
                replyChannel.Reply()
                // We do NOT do return! messageLoop() here
        with 
        | exc -> 
            printfn "%s" exc.Message
        }
    // start the loop 
    messageLoop() 
    )
```

and I can see the timout message printed in the console, but the program never ends: what am I missing?

This is how I'm calling the `printerAgent` in my code

```
printerAgent.PostAndReply( (fun replyChannel -> Shutdown replyChannel), 10000)
```

Notice that with `inbox.Receive()` it eventually terminates fine after a few minutes but my objective is setting a timeout (for example of 30 seconds) instead.

Comment: This might be relevant to you: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/10720

Comment: @JimFoye Interesting, thanks! Though I see that in that case it is disposed outside the recursive loop so it isn't exactly the same situation...

Comment: Welcome to the F# community! It might help you to know that the `MailboxProcessor` has an `Error` event that you could handle. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805035/mailboxprocessor-and-exceptions

Comment: @ScottHutchinson thanks, well I'm doing `try ... with` because of the `inbox.Receive 30000`. In this moment I've realized that in one of my edits it got deleted and I've restored it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the **conceptual** problem. I can't terminate the message loop before I receive the final shutdown message (otherwise all the following `printerAgent.Post` messages sent by the program will simply remain **unprocessed** in the **queue**, without blocking the program with any error, and the final shutdown message, sent by a `printerAgent.PostAndReply` will timeout, also without blocking the program with any error).
I should return the message loop so it can actually continue after the timeout exactly as it happens for a normal received message:

```
with 
| exc -> 
    printfn "%s" exc.Message
    return! messageLoop() // important! I guess I can't really terminate the message loop from here
```

And at this point the program terminates in the same time: I just see a lot of `Timeout of Mailbox.Receive` printed in the console (every n=30 seconds while the message loop is idling waiting to receive a message, so they can be informative about the elapsed time).